# Naive Bayes and Logistic Regression Error Rate

Tags: machine-learning

I have been trying to figure out the correlation between the error rate and the number of features in both of these models. I watched some videos, and the creator of the video said that a simple model can be better than a complicated model. So I figured that the more features I had the greater the error rate would be. This did not prove to be true in my work, and when I had less features the error rate went up. I'm not sure if I'm doing this incorrectly, or if the guy in the video made a mistake. Can someone care to explain? I also am curious how features relate to Logistic Regression's error rate as well.

Comment: This isn't a programming question; http://stats.stackexchange.com is more appropriate.

Comment: That said, "a simple model can be better than a complicated model" doesn't mean a simple model is *always* better than a complicated model; there's a tradeoff. Otherwise a constant predictor would be the best possible model and there would be no such field as machine learning.

Comment: Thank you, I will ask my questions there from now on.

Comment: The complexity of a logistic regression classifier is identical to the Naive Bayes classifier if the event space is the same---they form a generative/discriminative pair, and have identical forms of classification rule. See http://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/nips01-discriminativegenerative.pdf

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Naive Bayes and Logistic Regression are a "generative-discriminative pair," meaning they have the same model form (a linear classifier), but they estimate parameters in different ways.

For feature x and label y, **naive Bayes** estimates a joint probability p(x,y) = p(y)*p(x|y) from the training data (that is, builds a model that could "generate" the data), and uses Bayes Rule to predict p(y|x) for new test instances. On the other hand, **logistic regression** estimates p(y|x) directly from the training data by minimizing an error function (which is more "discrimative").

These differences have implications for error rate:

1. When there are very few training instances, logistic regression might "overfit," because there isn't enough data to estimate p(y|x) reliably. Naive Bayes might do better because it models the entire joint distribution.
2. When the feature set is large (and sparse, like word features in text classification) naive Bayes might "double count" features that are correlated with each other, because it assumes that each p(x|y) event is independent, when they are not. Logistic regression can do a better job by naturally "splitting the difference" among these correlated features.

If the features really are (mostly) conditionally independent, both models might actually improve with more and more features, provided there are enough data instances. The problem comes when the training set size is small relative to the number of features. Priors on naive Bayes feature parameters, or regularization methods (like L1/Lasso or L2/Ridge) on logistic regression can help in these cases.

Comment: Note that priors on NB parameters play the same role as regularization in LR---indeed it's possible to interpret regularization as a prior on the LR parameters.